# Author and affiliation only in chapters in a report class

Tags: chapters, report, authblk

EDITED
I am writing a thesis in report class and should show separate authors for each chapter. While the authors show up, they do not format into authblk format. Does anyone have an idea of what I could be doing wrong? 
The code for my main tex is

````
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{Something clever}
\author{Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}

\chapter*{Dedication}

\chapter*{Declaration}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}

\tableofcontents 

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Chapters/introduction} 

\chapter{Title of Chapter}
\input{Chapters/chap2}

\chapter{Title of Chapter}
\input{Chapters/chap3}

\chapter{Title of Chapter}
\input{Chapters/chap4}

\printbibliography

\end{document}``` 

While in the chapters the code is:
\title{something clever}
\author[1]{Name1}
\author[2]{Name2}
\author[1]{Name3}
\author[1]{Name4}
\affil[1]{af1}
\affil[2]{af2}
\date{}                     
\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract}
````

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the `\maketitle` command can be used only once in a document. If I remember correctly after its first use it redefines itself to do nothing. Perhaps you can define your own version of `\maketitle`, say `\mymaketitle`, that does not do this (on my system the `report.cls` code is in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base`) just picking out the relevant bits (do you really need a title after the chapter heading?).

Comment: Thank you for this comment @PeterWilson - I tried what you suggested, and completely removed the \maketitle. The author names now show up, but without affiliations. I edited the code in the question.